# Limiting the number of decimals in a dataframe with strings (R)

Tags: string, r, decimal, max

I would like to limit the number of decimals when a data frame is imported. My .txt input have 16 decimals to each row in collumn "Value". In a same collumns it can have numbers and strings, at same time. My dataframe look like that:

```
Value 

0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
NC
...
```

My expected dataframe

```
Value
0.20202156
0.20202156
0.20202156
0.20202156
NC
...
```

Real input (DF) that not works:

```
DF <- "NE001358.Log.R.Ratio
    -0.0970369274475688
    0.131893549586039
    0.0629266495860389
    0.299559132381831
    -0.0128804337656807
    0.0639743960526874
    0.0271669351886552
    0.322395363972391
    0.179591292893632
            NC"

DF <- read.table(text=DF, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: For your example, assuming `NC` means `NA` (not calculated/not available), maybe: `read.table(text=DF, header = TRUE, colClasses="numeric", na.strings="NC")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` on character vectors to cut them down.  Here we take only the first ten characters in the string.

```
> DF
##               Value
## 1 0.202021561664556
## 2 0.202021561664556
## 3 0.202021561664556
## 4 0.202021561664556
## 5                NC

> DF$Value <- substring(DF$Value, 1, 10)
> DF
##        Value
## 1 0.20202156
## 2 0.20202156
## 3 0.20202156
## 4 0.20202156
## 5         NC
```

But since these are log ratios, they should really be numeric.  In your DF data at the bottom of your post, you could wrap `substring` in `as.numeric` and `NA` values will replace "NC" entries.

```
> DF[,1] <- as.numeric(substring(DF[,1], 1, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `as.numeric` and `format`:

```
num <- as.numeric(as.character(DF[,1]))
ifelse(is.na(num), DF[,1], format(num, nsmall=8))
#  [1] "-0.09703693" " 0.13189355" " 0.06292665" " 0.29955913" "-0.01288043" " 0.06397440" " 0.02716694"
#  [8] " 0.32239536" " 0.17959129" "NC"
```

If you wanted to limit significant digits instead of digits after the decimal place, you should use the `digits` option instead of `nsmall`. If you don't like the leading space at the beginning of numbers, use `trim=TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
DF$NE001358.Log.R.Ratio <- as.character(DF$NE001358.Log.R.Ratio)
DFn <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(DF[,1]))
DF[!is.na(DFn),] <- format(DFn,nsmall=8)[!is.na(DFn)]
DF
```